# Wordpress multisites error occur while adding new site

Tags: wordpress, multisite

**The link you followed has expired.** the error is shown when trying to add new network site. But confusion is error_log empty and wp debug having 0 error. The setup contains more than 75 sites. Any suggestion to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue and found that I simply needed to bump up my PHP Options to allow for higher max post size.. went from 8MB to 16MB and that resolved for me..

HTH,
Q.